# Jquery variable use in function

Tags: jquery, function

I have problem with jquery. I need to use variable date and time in function process but I do not how. Please can you anyone help me. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input[name="date"]').change(function(){
    var date = $('input[name="date"]').val();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
});

$('input[name="time"]').change(function(){
    var time = $('input[name="time"]').val();
}); 


function process(){

}
});
```

Comment: how is `process` called?

Comment: Any idea what the function 'process' would do?

Comment: an easy solution is to read the values within the method like `function process(){
     var date = $('input[name="date"]').val();
}` - else you can pass them as parameters

Comment: The problem is that date is input date which is changing to that is why there is .change. I tried Arun P Johnny solution but it does not work.

Comment: Function process is only example I only want to know how to get variable into this function. As I wrote before there is problem with changing that is why I can not use var date = $('input[name="date"]).val();.Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a game of variable scopes. You can only use variables in your scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope my understanding is correct i.e. you want to call function process() everytime when the date/time changes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var date, time; // declare them on top

    $('input[name="date"]').change(function(){
        date = $('input[name="date"]').val();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
        process();
    });

    $('input[name="time"]').change(function(){
        time = $('input[name="time"]').val();
        process();
    }); 

    function process(){
        // use date, time here
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect this solution work exactly as I need. Thank you and others for your help.

Comment: This is the same answer that Java_User gave 5 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var date; //declared global
var time;//declared global
$('input[name="date"]').change(function(){
    date = $('input[name="date"]').val();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
});

$('input[name="time"]').change(function(){
    time = $('input[name="time"]').val();
}); 


function process(){
 //use date, time var as needed.
}
});
```

Comment: I tried use console.log in function process and console show this: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: This is a general error that will show in chrome console. You can safely ignore them. This has got nothing to do with your code. If you nedd to remove these warnings you can use `strict mode`.

Comment: Thank Makesh Sapkal add in your code process() and console.log is function. Thank you for your fast help.

Comment: Don't add comments in your answer; this post is fine just like it is.

Answer (score 1):

I know two answers have been given already, but here's another approach you could adopt; cache the selectors for date and time fields, and use those within the context of `process()`:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $date = $('input[name="date"]'),
    $time = $('input[name="time"]');

    function process()
    {
        // use $date.val() and $time.val()
    }

    $date.on('change', function() {
        $('#date').text(date);
        process();
    });

    $time.on('change', process);
});
```

The advantage is that you don't start with an undefined date or time variable, because they're already references to their corresponding fields on the page.